# Attach method to another class in restricted context in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

Is it possible to attach my own methods to another class, in limited region ?

If so, could anyone show me a better practice, or is it supposed to use something like `deligate` to do this?

The situation is like this : In class A that receive, generate and pass out instance of class B,
I want to attach some method onto those `b`s, without leaving those new methods accessible outside class A.

Answer (score 0):

These are called [singleton methods](http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2011/02/22/ruby-singleton-methods-and-singleton-classes/).  You can add methods to any object, only affecting that instance, not the entire class it was created from.

```
some_object = Whatever.new
other_object = Whatever.new

class << some_object
  def another_method
    ...
  end
end

some_object.another_method # works
other_object.another_method # error: no such method another_method
```

You can also use `define_singleton_method`:

```
some_object.define_singleton_method(:foo) do |arg1, arg2|
  puts "Called with #{arg1} and #{arg2}"
end

some_object.foo(7, 8)
```

There's also `instance_eval`, but you get the idea ;)

Comment: Thanks. But this alone still cannot hide the methods from being invoked outside. To `undef` those methods before passing `b`s out seems tedious but possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a private method in class B that takes an A object as an argument and uses `instance_variable_get`, `instance_variable_set`, and `send` to access whatever data from the object you want.  This is pretty ugly though.